# Remove ALL traces of Xcode from Lion

Tags: xcode

How do I remove EVERY single trace of Xcode from my system?

I'm having lot's of issues, and need to clean my entire system from Xcode.

-Re-installing Mac is not an option-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Terminal and, assuming that you have Xcode installed in the default `/Developer` folder, enter the following command:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

You'll need to enter your password.

This runs Xcode's own uninstall utility.